# How do I get the first character out of a string?

Tags: string, rust

I want to get the first character of a [`std::str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html). The method [`char_at()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_at) is currently unstable, as is [`String::slice_chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/std/string/struct.String.html#method.slice_chars).

I have come up with the following, but it seems excessive to get a single character and not use the rest of the vector:

```
let text = "hello world!";
let char_vec: Vec<char> = text.chars().collect();
let ch = char_vec[0];
```

Answer (score 211, accepted):

UTF-8 does not define what "character" is so it depends on what you want. In this case, `char`s are Unicode scalar values, and so the first `char` of a `&str` is going to be between one and four bytes.

If you want just the first `char`, then don't collect into a `Vec<char>`, just use the iterator:

```rust
let text = "hello world!";
let ch = text.chars().next().unwrap();
```

Alternatively, you can use the iterator's [`nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth) method:

```rust
let ch = text.chars().nth(0).unwrap();
```

Bear in mind that elements preceding the index passed to `nth` will be consumed from the iterator.

Comment: You  might also want to look at whether you really want the first _grapheme_.

Comment: This gives the `n`th code unit, but `char_at` gives the code unit starting at byte `n`. The latter is more useful because most string operations deal in byte indices. This is equivalent to `char_at` (and also constant time):`text[i..].chars().next().unwrap()`

Comment: @delnan: I would argue that actually using `char_at` is slightly dangerous as the index might be *in* a code unit.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Then you get a panic, not corrupted data (both with `char_at` and the slicing workaround). If you write your code properly Unicode-aware (i.e., using the existing string methods and iterators) that doesn't happen either. And using code point indices isn't really workable, since (as I said before) most string operations don't deal with those. *Mixing* code point indices and byte indices is more dangerous than either.

Comment: @delnan: Yes, code point indices would not work in O(1) anyway. However when someone asks for the n-th character, they might be asking for the n-th codepoint or the n-th grapheme cluster, but it is unlikely they are asking for the n-th byte.

Comment: @MatthieuM. But nobody ever asks for the n-th character. Well, programmers do, but only while devising an algorithm to solve some other problem that doesn't ask for the n-th character. All text processing I've ever seen can be done with byte indices, though it may require the programmer to think differently.

Comment: @delnan: I agree, any time I've seen some ask for the n-th character it was some school assignment or such "pointless" exercise.

Comment: It's because text isn't a list of chars

Comment: How well does this generalize to nth character, not just first?

Comment: So slightly late to the party ;) does anyone know to what this compiles down to? It still feels like a lot of magic is going on here for something that could potentially be less than a handful of instructions on the CPU.

Comment: or am I dramatically underestimating what text processing usually means in CPU instructions?

Comment: @KayleeTheMech I suspect you're dramatically underestimating what the compiler can do optimization wise. See here https://godbolt.org/z/Waa8hfza4

In short: with a literal, it will compile the entire thing away. With a normal function, you get a bounds check, and a series of movzxs.

Answer (score 13):

If you only want to test for it, you can use [`starts_with()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.starts_with):

```
"rust".starts_with('r')
"rust".starts_with(|c| c == 'r')
```

Comment: Are you able to explain what those two examples do?

Comment: @MikeB 
The first one compares the first character with a constant – so you definitely need to know what you are looking for beforehand. 
The second one passes it to a closure where it can be acted upon.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a function that returns the head of a `&str` and the rest:

```
fn car_cdr(s: &str) -> (&str, &str) {
    for i in 1..5 {
        let r = s.get(0..i);
        match r {
            Some(x) => return (x, &s[i..]),
            None => (),
        }
    }

    (&s[0..0], s)
}
```

Use it like this:

```
let (first_char, remainder) = car_cdr("test");
println!("first char: {}\nremainder: {}", first_char, remainder);
```

The output looks like:

```
first char: t
remainder: est
```

It works fine with chars that are more than 1 byte.

Comment: Seems [like this would be simpler](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c1a86a9de2b277ce571e5186eae85b7c&version=stable).

Comment: Shepmaster - your version is indeed simpler.  But, I'm worried about the chars() function - it looks to me as if it scans the entire string and parses that into a vector or something, whereas my code only looks at the first 4 characters of the string, at most.  But, perhaps I am misunderstanding how chars() works?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say "first 4 bytes" not "first 4 characters"

Comment: @Sean you probably know by now, but chars() returns an iterator. Iterators are lazily evaluated (and zero-cost, meaning the compiler rewrites them at compile-time), so it should actually be quite efficient.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is pretty straight forward

```
let text = "hello world!";
let c: char = text.chars().next().unwrap();
```

next() takes the next item from the iterator 
To “unwrap” something in Rust is to say, “Give me the result of the computation, and if there was an error, panic and stop the program.”

Answer (score 3):

Get the first single character out of a string **w/o** using the rest of that string:

```
let text = "hello world!";
let ch = text.chars().take(1).last().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have something similar to Haskell's [head function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:head) and [tail function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:tail) for such cases.

I wrote this function to act like `head` and `tail` together (doesn't match exact implementation)

```rust
pub fn head_tail<T: Iterator, O: FromIterator<<T>::Item>>(iter: &mut T) -> (Option<<T>::Item>, O) {
    (iter.next(), iter.collect::<O>())
}
```

Usage:

```rust
// works with Vec<i32>
let mut val = vec![1, 2, 3].into_iter(); 
println!("{:?}", head_tail::<_, Vec<i32>>(&mut val));
// works with chars in two ways
let mut val = "thanks! bedroom builds YT".chars();
println!("{:?}", head_tail::<_, String>(&mut val));
// calling the function with Vec<char>
let mut val = "thanks! bedroom builds YT".chars();
println!("{:?}", head_tail::<_, Vec<char>>(&mut val));
```

> **NOTE**: The head_tail function doesn't `panic!` if the iterator is empty. *If this matched Haskell's head/tail output, this would have thrown an exception if the iterator was empty*. It might also be good to use iterable trait to be more compatible to other types.

Answer (score -4):

The accepted answer is a bit ugly!

```
let text = "hello world!";

let ch = &text[0..1]; // this returns "h"
```

Comment: This answer is **completely wrong** for non-ASCII data. Try `&"日本語"[0..1]`

Comment: That is briefly covered in that chapter of the book ("*`world` would be a slice that contains a pointer **to the 6th byte** of `s` and a length value of 5*", emphasis mine) and in [much more detail later](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch08-02-strings.html#bytes-and-scalar-values-and-grapheme-clusters-oh-my).

Comment: This may not be what OP wanted. But it helped me get the first character as a string. Exactly what I wanted! Thanks, @FeFiFoFu :)

Comment: @Prajwal, this only works because each letter of the string is considered 1 byte for ASCII-composed strings. However, if your string uses multiple bytes to encode a character, then this will not work effectively and Rust will panic if splitting character bytes. Therefore, this method is not highly favored as fullproof and safe.