# How to get the last character of a &str?

Tags: string, rust

In Python, this would be `final_char = mystring[-1]`.  How can I do the same in Rust?

I have tried

```
mystring[mystring.len() - 1]
```

but I get the error `the type 'str' cannot be indexed by 'usize'`

Comment: [Please format your code carefully](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code).

Comment: I've adjusted the error message format as requested

Comment: See also [Getting a single character out of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30811107/155423).

Comment: By character you mean unicode codepoint?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Not sure what a unicode codepoint is, but basically, what I  was trying to do was if I had `abcd` as my string, I would want to get `d` as the final char. My current use case did not involve the use of strings like `あいうえお`, but if so, then I would have liked to get the final char `お`.

Comment: @BB The question you should perhaps answer, mostly for yourself, is whether the final "character" of `café` is `é` or `´`. If it should be `é`, you want to iterate by graphemes instead of `char`s.

Comment: See also [Why is capitalizing the first letter of a string so convoluted in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38406793/155423)

Comment: Likewise, what do you want the second-to-last character of "Åström" and "Åström" to be? Welcome to [precomposed characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character); they [have different answers](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=37f106fbc7b537edf0ea66b64ed8b63f&version=stable).

Comment: @trentcl I would expect the final "character" of `café` to be `é`. You mentioned graphemes, and I did some googling to check it out (for potential future use cases). Looks like I may have to import an external crate to do so as mentioned here: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-do-you-iterate-over-grapheme-clusters-of-a-string-in-rust/11338/2

Comment: @Shepmaster it looks like using rust for text wrangling (of non ascii text) would prove to be a fairly difficult exercise. Although, I believe python also had these difficulties prior to python 3.

Comment: @BB I think you are looking at it backwards. Text processing is **hard** because human languages are complicated and encoding them into computers is also complicated. Rust has a small set of opinions (e.g. that strings are UTF-8), but otherwise has to be hands-off in order to allow programmers to build the correct abstractions they need for their cases. As other people have mentioned, thinking of strings as bags of characters is ultimately incorrect because what a "character" is  is poorly defined to start with in our global world.

Comment: @Shepmaster That makes sense. I haven't had to do any text wrangling with "non-generic" characters in years, But I do remember the previous experiences to be fairly frustrating.

Comment: @BB Python 3 made great strides in correct Unicode handling, but it still doesn't offer an easy way to work with graphemes -- Rust (with the `unicode-segmentation` crate) is actually better in this regard. If you copy and paste `"café"[-1]` into your Python interpreter, it probably won't give you `"é"`.

Comment: @trentcl You're right, I didn't get `"é"`, I got `'́'`, whatever that is.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That is how you get the last `char` (which may not be what you think of as a "character"):

```
mystring.chars().last().unwrap();
```

Use `unwrap` only if you are sure that there is at least one char in your string.

---

**Warning**: About the general case (do the same thing as `mystring[-n]` in Python): UTF-8 strings are not to be used through indexing, because indexing is not a O(1) operation (a string in Rust is not an array). Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24542608/4498831) for more information.

However, if you want to index from the end like in Python, you must do this in Rust:

```
mystring.chars().rev().nth(n - 1) // Python: mystring[-n]
```

and check if there is such a character.

If you miss the simplicity of Python syntax, you can write your own extension:

```
trait StrExt {
    fn from_end(&self, n: usize) -> char;
}

impl<'a> StrExt for &'a str {
    fn from_end(&self, n: usize) -> char {
        self.chars().rev().nth(n).expect("Index out of range in 'from_end'")
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", "foobar".from_end(2)) // prints 'b'
}
```

Comment: `mystring.chars().last().unwrap()` looks easier to read, and is more concise. Is there a way to use it without `unwrap?`.  I had the impression that using `unwrap` was discouraged.

Comment: @BB [Pattern matching.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/book/patterns.html)

Comment: @erip Haven't gotten to that part of the book yet, but thanks for the headsup!

Comment: @BB Best of luck!

Comment: @BB It should also be noted that this is an O(n) operation in Rust, as opposed to Python's O(1).  You *should not* treat strings like arrays.

Comment: @DK Well, I was hoping to get the canonical way to do it, since I figured that getting the final element of a string was a fairly common operation.  I didn't have much luck googling for the answer however. Does rust have a O*(1) version for this as well?

Comment: @DK To clarify, getting the last character is an O(1) operation. Getting the nth character from either end is O(n) where n is the index.

Comment: @interjay Thanks!

Comment: _"I had the impression that using `unwrap` was discouraged"_ It's a matter of whether [to `panic!` or not to `panic!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch09-03-to-panic-or-not-to-panic.html). `unwrap` is to express that any potential error coming from there is irrecoverable and should not happen. There still are legitimate cases for this.

Comment: @E_net4: I still prefer `expect`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I've had this conversation before. :) Feel free to replace `unwrap` with `expect` above. The latter can often be better, but it's also noise if the only message you can think of is "IT SHOULD WORK!!!1".

Answer (score 22):

One option is to use [slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch04-03-slices.html#string-slices). Here's an example:

```
let len = my_str.len();
let final_str = &my_str[len-1..];
```

This returns a string slice from position `len-1` through the end of the string. That is to say, the last *byte* of your string. If your string consists of only ASCII values, then you'll get the final character of your string.

The reason why this only works with ASCII values is because they only ever require one byte of storage. Anything else, and Rust is likely to panic at runtime. This is what happens when you try to slice out one byte from a 2-byte character.

For a more detailed explanation, please see the strings section of [the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-02-strings.html).

Comment: Saying that a solution has problems *but not stating what those problems are* creates a very poor answer. Links to external resources are great, but any pertinent information needs to be included in the answer itself.

Comment: *That is, the final value contained in the string.* — this is not true unless you are dealing with ASCII-only text; which is less and less true as time progresses. Think about emoji.

Answer (score 4):

As [@Boiethios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4498831/boiethios) mentioned

```
let last_ch = mystring.chars().last().unwrap();
```

Or

```
let last_ch = codes.chars().rev().nth(0).unwrap();
```

I would rather have (how hard is that!?)

```
let last_ch = codes.chars(-1); // Not implemented as rustc 1.56.1
```